# Fingerprint option is not visible in settings in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, users, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 in my Mi Notebook Ultra and I am unable to see the Fingerprint option under `Settings>Users`. My settings page look like this -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF60I.png)

Following is the output of `lsusb` command, and I think `FPC Sensor Controller` is my fingerprint device -

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 10a5:9200 FPC FPC Sensor Controller
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05c8:03ec Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried to install `fprintd` using following commands to fix this, but no luck so far and the problem still persists.

```
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
sudo pam-auth-update
# rebooted the machine after these commands
```

I found various versions of `fprintd` online from various creators. Do I need to install a specific verion for my use case. Can someone help me with this issue ?

Edit: I came across this list of [Unsupported devices](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/wiki/-/wikis/Unsupported-Devices) and it looks like my device isnt supported yet. Is there a different driver or tool that I can use to make my fingerprint sensor run? Or, is there a way to reverse engineer `fprintd` to support my sensor?

Comment: Only a few sensors are supported.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks.
Just came across the list of unsupported devices. Please check the comment. Are you aware of any other ways to make my fingerprint running?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's web site, and ask them about Linux support. `fprintd` is open source, so you _could_, if you were a knowledgeable software developer;  and could find out the hardware characteristics of the fingerprint sensor, add support to `fprintd`. But probably not.

Comment: @Rishabh Please share the list of unsupported devices